# Using pascal data into php

Tags: php, mysql, pascal

I'm working with some php and need some help. Basically I have a script which sends a string from pascal to a php file which then gets posted into mysql.

I was wondering how I would go about this in the php and mysql table?

```
if test then
begin
TakeScreenshot(main screen)
error := bitmaptostring(the screenshot);
getpage('website.com/error.php?bitmap=error);
end;
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of tutorials about how to use GET values and connecting to databases.

Comment: Im not sure where to start, im pretty new with php and would like someone to help me with a little depth :) sorry for being a noob

Comment: It's not about being a noob or not. But in general people will be kinder and more keen to answer questions if they see that the asker has put some work into trying to solve the problem before they ask the question. Also welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, I've been reading into stuff like this which i presume is something along the lines of $value= (Then pascal to php here) then it sends $Value to the mysql table

Comment: The point of this site is to provide answers which will help others in future. If you've accidentally included private information, tell a mod. If it's only relevant to you, it should be deleted/closed. That said, welcome to SO and hope to see you in future

Comment: @Bradly: Once you've received answers, don't delete the text of your question. If you don't want the question here, delete the entire question, not just the text contained in it.

Comment: @Bradly: As I said, if you don't want the question seen, **delete it**. There's a link to do so right below the tags; you can access it if you're logged in under the same account you used to post the question.

Comment: I can't. I flagged it for a moderator and in the mean time I would prefer the code to be kept hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this to be kept private?  I don't see anything sensitive in the posted code.

Comment: @BradlySpicer It's possible to see the code by clicking the "Edited n minutes ago" link above the editors icon - it's not private at all unless you delete it. Even then, users with >10k rep can see it.

Comment: In that case I will wait for a mod to delete it. Thank you :)

Comment: We don't delete questions for no good reason once someone has taken the time to answer them for you.  Please explain why you think this needs to be deleted.

Comment: @BradlySpicer - Also, you should know that if you delete your questions, you'll eventually get banned automatically from posting new questions. Remember, the point of Stack Overflow is not just to help you, but to help future visitors for years to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so what you want to do is to get the value from the url which you do like this:

```
$value = $_GET['bitmap'];
```

And to connect to mysql in php is pretty easy, and is something like this.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(col_1, col_2) VALUES(val_1, val_2)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

I'm not really familiar with how to use mysqli(but it is prefferred over mysql_connect) so i recomend that you read up on it beforehand:

[PHP manual: MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)